# broadcom will not connect to wireless, ubuntu 12.04 on dell studio 1749

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, broadcom

I have trawled through a multitude of questions regarding this problem, tried many of the given solutions and still the problem persists.

Ethernet works fine but wireless is stuck in a loop trying to connect to my router with the security prompt popping every so often to ask me for the wireless key (which has been entered correctly)

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

edit > result of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Net`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

yes driver has been installed and activated from Additional Drivers

Comment: Four lines of text+no punctuation=hard to read. Anyway, we'll need more info from you, please add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Net` to the question.

Comment: Did you install the Broadcom proprietary drivers for your chip?

Comment: Added result of your given command. Will try to punctuate correctly from now on.

Comment: I have installed the driver.

Comment: OK, seems to have solved itself when I deleted the wireless network that was saved in my connections, and started afresh.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```